# How to get more current out of a simple USB-C breakout board

Tags: arduino, current, usb-c

Trying to see if anyone has experience with USB breakout boards.

I am trying to get more current out of this setup and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using a simple USB-C board (picture below). I connected pullup resistors by wiring cc1 and cc2 each to a 22k resistor and back to V+. The specs show that this would allow up to 1.5A. The usb-C cable is connected to a block that supports 2100mA. I am showing only 50mA and it is not enough to drive my small water pump. Any advice is appreciated.

[image: USB-C breakout board]

Comment: How did you measure 50mA? What did you use, and where did you connect it?

Comment: Where did you read that you have to pull CC1 and CC2 up? They need to be pulled to GND to activate Vbus.

Comment: What if you flip your cable? Did you use two resistors or one? Common mistake is trying to use one instead of one each.

Comment: This board likely already has 5.1kΩ resistors to ground for each CC line (see image).

Comment: @Codo Yes, good spot.

Comment: Only the power source (aka DFP) will indicate the maximum current. The power sink (aka UFP) must always have a fixed pull-down value of 5.1kΩ. Try to measure the maximum current without any additional resistors (except for the ones already on the board). If you have an intelligent power supply, it will likely limit the current. You might be better off with an old non-USB-C power supply.

Comment: @Finbarr I measured the current directly from terminals so short circuiting with my multimeter.

Comment: @Codo I've tried different usb blocks or power sources. They all ranged from a max output from 2100mA to 3A. Measuring max current by short circuiting still only gives me 50mA. I connected it straight to the water pump and it isn't being activated due to low current. I know this breakout board can handle 3A I just don't know how to get it there.

Comment: The motor in the pump will draw 2-3x the steady state current on startup, just FYI.

Comment: @AlenRamic - Shorting the terminals with a meter is NOT the way to measure the current capability. If the source is not current limited it may damage the meter or the voltage source. Learn how to use your meter to measure current.

Comment: The majority of USB power supplies will simply shut down if you short-circuit them by attempting to measure current directly across the output - hence the 50mA you measure. It tries to start up, pumps out a bit of current (probably a significant spike at 2-3A, then shuts down for a while to recover then tries again. Your meter just averages that brief spike over the period of time.